# Testing mediator design pattern with Jest

Tags: javascript, testing, design-patterns, jestjs, mediator

I'm currently working on a web based Battleship game for one my [Odin Project](https://theodinproject.com) assignments. At some point I felt that the mediator pattern would be the perfect choice to deal with firing missiles for the player and the CPU. Now, my assignment encourages me to test the game thoroughly without `console.log` but with Jest. I've been able to test some features of the game but the mediator pattern is confusing. Mocking functions or modules is likely to be the right direction to go for but to be honest I've read heaps of guides and I've not been able to implement them (understanding mocks has been hard as well). The function `notifyAttack`inside `EventManager` has already been tested the old way with `console.log`.

Can anyone let me know what I'm doing wrong please?

**Event Manager**

```
export {EventManager}

const EventManager = {
  gameManager: GameManager,
  notifyAttack(who, coordinate){
    if(!who)
      throw new Error(`Unknown player`);
    else
      who === `CPU` ? GameManager.player.board.getAttack(coordinate) : GameManager.cpu.board.getAttack(coordinate);

    GameManager.turn = who;
  }
}
```

**Game Manager**

```
import {Player} from "./player";
export {GameManager}

const GameManager = {
  turn: undefined,
  player: undefined,
  cpu: Player(),
}
```

**Player**

```
import {coordinate, GameBoard} from './gameboard';
import { EventManager } from './eventmanager';
export {Player}

const playerActions = {
  eventManager: EventManager,
  fire(coordinate){
    this.eventManager.notifyAttack(this.name, coordinate);
  }
}

function Player(name){
  const player = Object.create(playerActions);
  player.board = GameBoard();
  name === undefined ? player.name = `CPU`: player.name = name;
  return player;
}
```

**GameBoard**

```
import {  Ship } from "./ship"
export {GameBoard, coordinate, shipOrientation, tile}

function coordinate(x,y){
  const boardSize = 10;
  if(x > boardSize || x < 1)
    throw new Error(`X coordinate is out of boundaries`);
  if(y > boardSize || y < 1)
    throw new Error(`Y coordinate is out of boundaries`);
  return{x:x, y:y}
}

function tile(coordinate, id){
  return{coordinate: coordinate, id: id}
}

const shipOrientation = {
  HORIZONTAL: Symbol(`horizontal`),
  VERTICAL: Symbol(`vertical`),
}

const gameboardActions = {
  placeShips(shipType, orientation, inputCoordinate){
    const ship = Ship(shipType);
    ship.ID = `${inputCoordinate.x},${inputCoordinate.y}`;
  
    this.tiles.forEach(tile=>{
      if(tile.coordinate.x === inputCoordinate.x && tile.coordinate.y === inputCoordinate.y)
      throw new Error(`There's already an object on that input coordinate`);
    })

    if(orientation === shipOrientation.HORIZONTAL){
      if(inputCoordinate.x + ship.length > this.size)
        throw new Error(`Part of ship is out of board X boundary`);
      for(let i = 0; i<ship.length; ++i)
        this.tiles.push(tile(coordinate(inputCoordinate.x+i, inputCoordinate.y), `${ship.ID}`));
    }else if(orientation === shipOrientation.VERTICAL){
      if(inputCoordinate.y + ship.length > this.size)
        throw new Error(`Part of ship is out of board Y boundary`);
      for(let i = 0; i<ship.length; ++i)
        this.tiles.push(tile(coordinate(inputCoordinate.x, inputCoordinate.y+i), `${ship.ID}`));
    }else
      throw new Error(`Undefined ship orientation`);

    this.shipsLog.set(`${ship.ID}`,ship);
  },

  getAttack(inputCoordinate){
    let isShip, ID;
    this.tiles.forEach(tile=>{
      if(tile.coordinate.y===inputCoordinate.y&&tile.coordinate.x===inputCoordinate.x&&tile.id){
        ID = tile.id;
        return isShip = true;
      }
    })

    if(isShip){
      this.shipsLog.get(ID).hit()
      if(this.shipsLog.get(ID).isSunk){
        this.removeShip(ID);
        this.checkSunkFleet();
      }
    }else
      this.tiles.push(tile(inputCoordinate, undefined));
  },

  removeShip(ID){
    this.shipsLog.delete(ID);
    for(let i = 0; i<this.tiles.length; ++i)
      if(this.tiles[i].id===ID)
        this.tiles.splice(i,1);
  },

  checkSunkFleet(){
    this.shipsLog.size === 0 ? this.sunkFleet=true:this.sunkFleet=false;
  }

}


function GameBoard (){
  const gameboard = Object.create(gameboardActions);
  gameboard.shipsLog = new Map();
  gameboard.tiles= []; 
  gameboard.size= 10;
  gameboard.sunkFleet = false;

    return gameboard;
}
```

**Jest test**

```
import {GameBoard, coordinate} from "./gameboard";
import {GameManager} from './gamemanager';
import {Player} from "./player";
import {EventManager} from "./eventmanager";

GameManager.player = Player(`Pablo`);

describe(`Player set up`, ()=>{
  test(`Player's name is Pablo`,()=>{
    expect(GameManager.player.name).toMatch(/^[A-Z]+$/i); 
  });
  test(`Player has a board to play with`, ()=>{
    expect(GameManager.player.board).toMatchObject(GameBoard());
  });
})

describe(`Player's actions`,()=>{
  test(`Pablo fires a missile, he misses ship target though`, ()=>{
    const myCoordinate = coordinate(5,5);
    const spy = jest.spyOn(EventManager, 'notifyAttack')
    GameManager.player.fire(myCoordinate);
    expect(spy).toBeCalled();
    expect(GameManager.cpu.getAttack).toBeCalledWith(myCoordinate);
    expect(GameManager.cpu.shipsLog.has(`${myCoordinate.x}, ${myCoordinate.y}`));
  })
})
```

So the flow goes in this way:

1. A Player already set up in `GameManager` (Pablo) fires a missile by triggering `fire()`   inside the Player object
2. `fire()` reports `EventManager` who fires the missile and its coordinates
3. `EventManager` calls `CPU` `GameBoard` `getAttack()` method that records Pablo's missing missile

You guys might wonder why I'm using an `EventManager` instead of relying on `GameManager`. Basically, `GameManager` is in charge of changing turns, set up the game whereas `EventManager` specifically deals with the battle to prevent coupling between `Player` and `CPU`

I'd like to hear from you if you need more details for the question.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Well I found the answer after some struggle. Mocks are not the best idea in this situation, instead jest spies let me check if functions are called without changing the implementation like mocks so I wasn't far from the answer.

Here you go jest test code for future reference

```
describe(`Player's attack`,()=>{

  GameManager.cpu = Player();
  GameManager.cpu.board.placeShips(shipType.DESTROYER, shipOrientation.HORIZONTAL, coordinate(4,4))
  let myCoordinate = coordinate(5,5);
  const eventManager = jest.spyOn(EventManager, 'notifyAttack');
  const cpuGetsAttack = jest.spyOn(GameManager.cpu.board, 'getAttack')

  test(`Pablo fires a missile, he misses his target ship  though`, ()=>{
    GameManager.player.fire(myCoordinate);
    expect(eventManager).toBeCalled();
    expect(cpuGetsAttack).toBeCalledWith(myCoordinate);
    expect(GameManager.cpu.board.shipsLog.has(`${myCoordinate.x},${myCoordinate.y}`)).toBeFalsy();
    expect(GameManager.cpu.board.tiles).toContainEqual(tile(myCoordinate, undefined));
  });

  test(`Pablo fires a missile and hits his target ship`, ()=>{
    myCoordinate.x = 4;
    myCoordinate.y = 4;

    GameManager.player.fire(myCoordinate);
    expect(eventManager).toBeCalled();
    expect(cpuGetsAttack).toBeCalledWith(myCoordinate);
    expect(GameManager.cpu.board.shipsLog.has(`${myCoordinate.x},${myCoordinate.y}`)).toBeTruthy();
    expect(GameManager.cpu.board.tiles).toContainEqual(tile(myCoordinate, GameManager.cpu.id));
  });
});
```